# measure video playback delay on local computer

Tags: wpf, video, lag

We need to determine the delay imposed by hardware and software components of a video being shown on a local computer.

What I mean with delay is, the time spent decoding a frame, sending it over the wire (HDMI) to the monitor and the time it takes the monitor to show the frame (i.e. display lag).

We are measuring the user reactions to visual stimuli in the video and hence need to know the delay caused by the hardware/software toolchain when a playing a video. At the end of the day the delay shall be minimized.

We are currently playing the video with .net WPF MediaElement.

The video itself:

- codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10)(avc1)
- resolution: 720*578
- 25 FPS
- decoded format: Planar 4:2:0 YUV

I'd especially interested in:

- how to minimize the delay
- the penalty imposed by the managed environment
- how ffmeg or the microsoft media foundation coudl reduce delay

Comment: Why would it be so relevant to know the player delay? As you specified, the video is 25fps. That means the decoder can spend anything from 10ms up to 1/25s before the next frame is getting into the framebuffer. All you need to ensure is that your computer is fast enough to decode a frame within 1/25s, right? (1/2)

Comment: One pretty accurate solution and which we've been using for as long as we've been doing experiments, is measuring that delay using external hardware: get yourself a proper low-latency I/O card which can output a TTL pulse with a sub-mSec latency. In the software producing the video set an output high at the moment you issue the 'draw' command. Assuming the screen at that moment has at least a couple of pixels which go from black to non-black when the video starts playing, place a photodiode on those pixels. Finally measure delay between pulse and photodiode.

Comment: Btw if you want to measure reaction times accurately (as in, *really* accurate for e.g. psychophysics), the same system is really a must. Measure time between things appearing on the screen measured using photodiode, and hardware key presses. Don't do otherwise, your measured reaction times will simply be wrong.. Oh and  'reducing delay' is quite broad, but be sure to check video driver settings like pre-rendering, preallocate all decode components, eventually buffer parts or the whole file in memory.

Comment: (2/2) Any delay added by the hardware you would need to measure once only (as it should be constant). For example, a test setup/jig using a photo sensor, that can measure the delta time between the output of a graphics card turning a black screen to white. Also, don't use managed environments if you want to obtain very precise measurements of time differences between screen content changes and user reactions...

Comment: *as it should be constant* it *should*, but in real life it isn't. I've seen it happen too much. Typcial example: nvidia driver update, settings reset, oops, 3 frames of latency extra. Or just a once in a while there could be hiccups causing a frame to be missed, etc.

Comment: @stijn, i was talking about hardware delays, not delays introduced somewhere deep down the driver (these would be software-related delays). To get as precise measurements as possible, you should use framebuffer refreshes (or whatever they are called) as reference, not some arbitrary point somewhere up the multi-layered software cake. That said, it's probably hard/near impossible with OTS commercial hardware to do what i just suggested...

Comment: @elgonzo fair point, but in the end it usually does not matter: sure it's interesting to know hardware delay but that doesn't help when you want to know the total delay. Like the OP. Also these days the line between hardware and software sometimes shifts, sort of. Modern displays might run software as well. Fiddling with the settings might change delay. Still I'd consider a display hardware..

Comment: Btw care to expand on the framebuffer refresh comment? In the end you want to know exactly when X was on the screen. If you issue a render command, there's an unknown (?) time between issuing that command and X beig drawn on the actual screen. How does framebuffer refresh help getting a very precise measurement of when that happens? Is it also not part of the driver layer?

Comment: @stijn, as i said, it's probably not possible to realize such with OTS commercial PC components. I don't know exactly the accuracy and resultion demanded here, but i get the feeling an FPGA/ARM/MCU-based solution (which would do the video playback as well as timing the user reaction) would be better than attempting to work around the peculiar performance characteristics of a typical PC setup...

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your replies! I agree with you that, for accurate measurements an external device like @stijn suggested is mandatory - especially with non-CRT monitors that do a lot of visual signal post processing (to reduce blurring etc.) bevor the frame is actually shown on the screen. So without an external device one can never be sure if the image gets shown immediately or not. There is an article "Millisecond accuracy video display using OpenGL under Linux" from 2006 that describes that the delay of such a system is less than one tenth of a millisecond.

Comment: Another article (2014) describes that non-CRT monitors are nowadays fast enough for visual timing tasks. That is good news. Knowing that displaying an image present in a grafics cards buffer (and being able to measure the time it takes), I can focus on the software side like drivers, WPF MediaElement implementation etc. But this side is much harder to measure and I could only estimate the panalty by reading the documentation of the certain implementation...What do you think?